# Can we convert such 20:72:84(hh:mm:ss) duration to 21:13:24 (hh:mm:ss) format Without Loop?

Tags: excel, vbscript, wsh, vba

Is it Possible in VBScript to convert such 20:72:84(hh:mm:ss) duration to 21:13:24 (hh:mm:ss) format?

Yes obviously we can Loop through it but I want to avoid such `Loopy` technique.

**CODE**

As per the `Siddharth` solution - I just modified the code as it to fit with `VBScript platform`

```
Option Explicit


    Dim S
    S=Convert("23:61:61")
    MsgBox(s)


Function Convert(strTime) 'As String
    Dim timeArray() 
    Dim h , m , s 

    MsgBox("Hi")

    'On Error Resume Next

    timeArray = Split(strTime, ":")

    h = timeArray(0): m = timeArray(1): s = timeArray(2)

    REM If err then

        REM MsgBox(err)
        REM err.clear
        REM Exit Function
    REM End if

    Do Until s < 60
        s = s - 60
        m = m + 1
    Loop

    Do Until m < 60
        m = m - 60
        h = h + 1
    Loop

    Do Until h < 24
        h = h - 24
    Loop

    Convert = Format(h, "00") & ":" & Format(m, "00") & ":" & Format(s, "00")

    'on Error Goto 0
    'Exit Function
'Whoa:
    'Convert = "Error! CYDD!" '<~~ CYDD : Check Your Data Dude :)
End Function
```

**EDIT1** I am getting  an error as `Type mismatch` to the line `timeArray = Split(strTime, ":")`

Thanks,

Comment: The question is: how can you GET such a value in the first place ?

Comment: @Tukai, there were some of your earlier questions exactly on this, what happened to those answers?

Comment: No positive comments on those I got,what they proposed was fit for excel sheet which are not dynamic.

Comment: @Tukai: What according to you should `23:61:61` or `24:61:61` convert to?

Comment: If there was a prize, for the craziest vbs questions, with the most impossible sample data sets, then you would be my winner everytime. That alone deserves recognition so against my better judgement I'm going to upvote this question ^_^

Comment: @SiddharthRout `23:61:61` -> `24:02:01` and `24:61:61` -> `25:02:01` . Please see me answer!

Comment: @tukai: Hmm that is why I asked this question ;) Shouldn't the time reset instead of increasing to 24 and then to 25? Ideally `23:61:61` should have become `00:02:01` and `24:61:61` should have become `01:02:01`

Comment: @SiddharthRout Yes i am comfortable with [h]:mm:ss format! means hours is the last platform so it can be increased beyond 24 but not the hours and minutes , as per my requirement! They should be 0:60 durations only!

Comment: @TukaiRakshit: Have posted an answer. Would be out for sometime and hence wont be able to reply immediately.

Comment: @SiddharthRout no issues it would work for me,So if any issue is there i will report you back! :-) thanks Mumbai again :-)

Comment: @TukaiRakshit: Sorry was out as I had mentioned earlier... Have updated the post with vbscript code....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Split the array
2. Add each part to an empty time using `dateadd()`
3. rebuild the time to a well formatted string using a stringbuilder

   ```
   ' This splits the string in an hours, minutes and seconds part.
   ' the hours will be in dArr(0), minutes in dArr(1) and seconds in dArr(2)
   dArr = split("20:72:84", ":")

   ' Add the hours to an empty date and return it to dt1 
   dt1 = dateadd("h", dArr(0), empty)

   ' Add the minutes to dt1. Note: Minutes are noted as "n" and not "m" because the
   ' "m" is reserved for months. To find out more about the dateadd() please look here:
   ' http://www.w3schools.com/vbscript/func_dateadd.asp
   ' When the minutes are bigger than they fit in the date, it automatically falls over to
   ' next hour.
   dt1 = dateadd("n", dArr(1), dt1)

   ' Also add the seconds (the third part of the array) to dt1, also the seconds
   ' automatically fall over when too large.
   dt1 = dateadd("s", dArr(2), dt1)

   ' Now that we created a date, we only have to format it properly. I find it the most easy
   ' way to do this is with a dotnet stringbuilder, because we can separate code and 
   ' format. The CreateObject creates the stringbuilder. We chain the AppendFormat
   ' and the ToString methods to it, so actually these are three statements in one.
   ' Mind the HH in the HH:mm:ss format string, hh means 12 hour notation, HH means 24
   ' hour notation.
   msgbox CreateObject("System.Text.StringBuilder").AppendFormat("{0:HH:mm:ss}", dt1).toString()
   ```

outputs `21:13:24`

**EDIT:** Extra comments by request of TS

Comment: this is the short calculation I was looking for. But Can you a bit explain the calculation that **"HOW"**? the 2nd and 3rd line will be enough! :-)

Comment: Explanation added, but please do some research on the internet if you want to find out how something works. Searching on vbscript+dateadd in google is enough. Try not to behave like an  [Help Vampire](http://slash7.com/2006/12/22/vampires/).

Comment: +1 because it's the *sensible* solution to the problem and because of the extra effort of explanation. (Perhaps you want to consider TimeSerial() instead of DateAdd()).

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you are trying?

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    Debug.Print Convert("23:61:61")
    Debug.Print Convert("24:61:61")
    Debug.Print Convert("20:72:84")
    Debug.Print Convert("Hello World")
End Sub

Function Convert(strTime As String) As String
    Dim timeArray() As String
    Dim h As Long, m As Long, s As Long

    On Error GoTo Whoa

    timeArray = Split(strTime, ":")

    h = timeArray(0): m = timeArray(1): s = timeArray(2)

    Do Until s < 60
        s = s - 60
        m = m + 1
    Loop

    Do Until m < 60
        m = m - 60
        h = h + 1
    Loop

    Do Until h < 24
        h = h - 24
    Loop

    Convert = Format(h, "00") & ":" & Format(m, "00") & ":" & Format(s, "00")

    Exit Function
Whoa:
    Convert = "Error! CYDD!" '<~~ CYDD : Check Your Data Dude :)
End Function
```

**SNAPSHOT**

[image]

**EDIT (FOLLOWUP)**

The code that I gave above is for `VBA-Excel` (*as it is one of your tags*)

For `VB-Script`, use this code

```
MsgBox Convert("23:61:61")
MsgBox Convert("24:61:61")
MsgBox Convert("20:72:84")
MsgBox Convert("Hello World")

Function Convert(strTime)
    Dim timeArray
    Dim h, m, s, hh, mm, ss

    On Error Resume Next

    timeArray = Split(strTime, ":", -1, 1)

    h = timeArray(0): m = timeArray(1): s = timeArray(2)

    If Err Then
        Err.Clear
        Exit Function
    End If

    Do Until s < 60
        s = s - 60
        m = m + 1
    Loop

    Do Until m < 60
        m = m - 60
        h = h + 1
    Loop

    ' As per latest request
    'Do Until h < 24
        'h = h - 24
    'Loop

    If Len(Trim(h)) = 1 Then hh = "0" & h Else hh = h
    If Len(Trim(m)) = 1 Then mm = "0" & m Else mm = m
    If Len(Trim(s)) = 1 Then ss = "0" & s Else ss = s

    Convert = hh & ":" & mm & ":" & ss

    On Error GoTo 0
End Function
```

HTH

Comment: I am not getting any output for any of the call in the code above! I think there is any hidden issue in the `code`.

Comment: one concern here is that I am getting the output as `00:02:01` for the input `23:61:61` . Which is not desired. These durations are resource work time calculations. So I need to made them intact.It should be `24:02:01`.

Comment: change `h < 24` to `h < 25` and `h = h - 24` to `h = h - 25`

Comment: Could you guide me to do so?

Comment: now the issue with your another input `24:61:61` - its giving me `00:02:01` - which is wrong again!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21770/discussion-between-siddharth-rout-and-tukai-rakshit)

Comment: Okay! Telling you When Seconds would have values > 59 than then 1 min should be added to the minutes numbers. That means hh:mm:ss format SS value should be <=59, otherwise minutes get increased by the amount. now same for minutes to Hours also. for hours every number is OKAy. as it is [h] format!

Comment: now say `21:22:60` should be rounded to `21:23:00` ; `21:59:60` should be rounded to `22:00:00` like these..

Comment: The comments are getting too long... Can you delete your above comments? Also what result are you expecting for `24:61:61`?

Comment: it should be `25:02:01` . Can we fix it globally? what I just explained!

Comment: Now It is Perfect,Tested with different inputs till now result is Good! one request to you that,please don't delete the link you have provided to read. I will read that.

Comment: Here it is again - http://ns7.webmasters.com/caspdoc/html/vbscript_split_function.htm

Comment: why do until loop? why not modulo?

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be quite obviously an "[XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/370758)": the OP is seeking a workaround to deal with a malformed piece of data, instead of figuring how the data is becoming malformed in the first place (and preventing it from happening).

`20:72:84` is not a logical representation of duration by *any* standard, and whatever created that string is erroneous.

*Technically*, according to [ISO-8601](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) (considered the "international standard for covering exchange of date and time related data"), [duration](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Durations) should be expressed as `PnYnMnDTnHnMnS`.

That said, I would also opt for `HH:MM:SS`... but it should [obviously?] never show more than 59 seconds or 59 minutes, any more than our decimal (aka, [Base 10](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal)) number system should count `...0.8, 0.9, 0.10, 0.11...`.  (lol, *"zero point eleven"*)

---

## Fixing the Duration

Regardless, it's an old question and we don't know how you got this strange number, but as others have suggested, I would use [`Split`](https://learn.microsoft.com/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/split-function) to fix it, although my preference is a more compressed form:

```
Function fixWonkyDuration(t As String) As String
    fixWonkyDuration = Format(((Split(t, ":")(0) * 60 + Split(t, ":")(1)) _
        * 60 + Split(t, ":")(2)) / 86400, "HH:mm:ss")
End Function
```

The function above will fix a "wonky" duration by converting each section into seconds, summing, then converting temporarily to a [`Date`](https://learn.microsoft.com/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/date-data-type) before using [`Format`](https://learn.microsoft.com/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/format-function-visual-basic-for-applications) to display it as intended.

It's important to note that neither the input *nor* output is a valid Excel [DateTime](https://learn.microsoft.com/office/vba/access/concepts/date-time/calculate-elapsed-time) ([`Date`](https://learn.microsoft.com/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/date-data-type)), so both are declared as [`String`](https://learn.microsoft.com/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/string-data-type)s.

### Example Usage:

```
MsgBox fixWonkyDuration("20:72:84")  'returns "21:13:24"
```

---

## Convert to Seconds <sub><sup>(for comparison, calculations, etc)</sup></sub>

Incidentally, when you have a *valid* duration in `HH:MM:SS` format, but want to do calculations or comparisons with it, it's easiest to first convert it to seconds with the help of [`TimeValue`](https://learn.microsoft.com/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/timevalue-function) and [`CDbl`](https://learn.microsoft.com/office/vba/language/concepts/getting-started/type-conversion-functions).

**The quickest method:**

```
Function DurationToSeconds(d As String) As Long
    DurationToSeconds = CDbl(TimeValue(d)) * 86400#
End Function
```

### Example Usage:

```
MsgBox DurationToSeconds("21:13:24")  'returns 76404
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can split into 3 variables: h,m and s. And then check if s>60. And if it is, m=m+s/60 and s=s%60. The same for the m variable:

```
if(m>60) then
    h=h+m/60
    m=m%60
```

Then, concate h, m and s.

Comment: thanks for your suggestions,but looking for any direct way to do that!

Comment: @pst Yeah! I can see that. Looking for any inbuilt function which can reduce these many lines of codes.So that such branching,and arithmetic would take time for my practical case where I would deal with 3500 rows and 25 such duration columns!

Comment: @TukaiRakshit Computers are fast (don't doubt this unless there is a *real test case*) and functions eliminate duplicate code.

Comment: @pst May I see your code - the approach you are suggesting me?

Comment: @peter I Agree, but lets see if anyone can give me such one shot approach for the same! Otherwise I would follow such conventional mathematics :-)

Comment: @peter why you deleted your post! It seems what I just told you,felt you bad.Sorry for that,I am waiting for any more alternative,If I really get it from some one ,it wouldn't be helpful for me only,all the others would get the same benefits. Still If you think I am wrong - I am very very Sorry! :-(

Answer (score 0):

This is too much text to put in a comment.

When you enter `20:72:33` into any cell that is on `General` format it will show you a serial number. E.g. `0.883715278`

Then you change the cell format to `Time`. And it gives you the format and data you want to see.

### **HOWEVER**,

The above statement only works as long as your seconds are **`below 60`**. If you enter `60, 61, 84`, '100', etc. **It doesn't work.**

So perhaps you can **jam** it like all the jamming codes perhaps you are using right now. ;)

It's as ugly as it could get. Do `mod 60` on `seconds` and then change cell format to Time. Or just as might as use what **Alex shows up there in his answer.** *It's clean and gurantees your the desired output mathematically.*

Comment: @Tukai BTW Alex's answer doesn't need you to have a `loop`.

Comment: @Siddharth please give me the link here,I need that reference to read!